# What is the meaning of "shortened for loop" and sort() function used in this perl script?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I'm not familiar about perl but trying to interpret perl codes.

Below code block is the part of the long code.

```
my @blacklist;
open my $fh, '<', '/var/cache/AllStatus.json';
close($fh);

my @json = decode_json(<$fh>);

push @blacklist, 1212, 2341, 3121, 5462;

my %outputs;
$outputs{$_} = [] for @blacklist;

foreach (sort { $a->{host_posting} cmp $b->{host_posting} } values %{$json[0]}) {
```

1. It looks like a shorted for loop. Can you explain the meaning of `$outputs{$_} = [] for @blacklist;` ?
2. Can you explain sort function in this code?
   -- In json file, there are keys named "host_posting". (It's for loop but cannot understand the meaning of `$a->{host_posting}` and `$b->{host_posting}`)

Also, is there any effective way to search this kind of syntax things from stackoverflow or google?

Comment: To your first question, print the `Dumper` of `%outputs` hash. `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(\%outputs);`.

Comment: Thank you @vkk05. But can you please explain the meaning of `print Dumper(\%outputs);` ? Thank you

Comment: See [this](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper).

Comment: It opens a file, closes it, *then* tries to read from the closed file handle. That's not going to work very well.

Comment: Hi @Shawn, thanks for your comment. It's the part of the long code. But can you let me know the meaning of the last foreach loop? There is no `$a` or `$b` defined at all. I cannot understand `$a->{host_posting}`. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, if you're just starting with Perl there are some rather complex concepts at work here. I wouldn't expect someone new to Perl to deal with array and hash references until they had mastered the basics of the language.

> ```
> my %outputs;
> ```

This declares a hash called `%outputs`.

> ```
> $outputs{$_} = [] for @blacklist;
> ```

This is a shortened way to write:

```
for my $item (@blacklist) {
  $outputs{$item} = [];
}
```

There are three pieces of syntax here.

```
for my VAR (LIST) {
  ...
}
```

This goes through all of the elements in a LIST one at a time. Each of the elements, in turn, is put into VAR and the block of code is executed. You can omit the VAR, in which case Perl uses `$_` instead.

```
$outputs{$_} = ...;
```

This sets the value associated with a key in a hash called `%outputs`. The value `$_` is going to be one of the elements from `@blacklist`.

```
[];
```

This creates an empty array and returns a reference to it.

So, taking those pieces and putting them together, your code creates a key/value pair in your `%outputs` hash for each of the elements in `@blacklist`. The key is the element from `@blacklist` and the value is a reference to an empty array.

> ```
> foreach (sort { $a->{host_posting} cmp $b->{host_posting} } values %{$json[0]}) {
> ```

This is the start of a `foreach` loop. This is the same as the `for` loop that we saw before.

```
$json[0]
```

This gets the first element from an array called `@json`.

```
%{$json[0]}
```

This assumes that the value stored in `$json[0]` is a reference to a hash. It then dereferences that reference to get back to the original hash.

```
values %{$json[0]}
```

This gets a list of the values from that hash.

```
sort { $a->{host_posting} cmp $b->{host_posting} } values %{$json[0]}
```

This gets a sorted version of that list of values.

A call to `sort` looks like this:

```
sort { SORTING_CODE } LIST
```

The input list is your list of values that you got from the hash. The sorting code is this:

```
$a->{host_posting} cmp $b->{host_posting}
```

I don't have time to explain how sorting code works (see [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort)) but this is assuming that each of the values in your list is a hash reference and it's sorting by the `host_posting` value within those hashes. The `->` is (in this case) the way to get from a hash reference to a value associated with a key - `$hash_ref->{key}`.

So, putting this code together, it gets the values (which are hash references) from the hash that is inside your JSON. It then sorts those values on the `host_posting` key and uses the resulting sorted list as the input for the `foreach` loop. The loop puts each value in turn into the `$_` variable and then executes the loop code block (which you haven't shown us).

Answer (score -1):

`$outputs{$_} = [] for @blacklist;`

all that's doing is defaulting all the items to an empty array.